# XBee, external libraries and passing structures as arguments

Tags: c++, struct, arduino, arguments, xbee

I have very weird problem with a library I am creating. The library will be used to communicate between Arduino modules using XBee Series 1 modules. Library is very simple wrapper library around Arduino XBee library.

I have one function that reads received packet and sends it back. At the moment it is implemented as a simple "echo" service - the function just displays the data received and sends it back to per-defined address.

At the moment I have three versions of this function, out of which one is not working.

1. A function taking no arguments: void processPacket()
2. A function taking structure as a value as an argument: void processPacket(valuesStruct valuesStructData) - THIS VERSION OF THE FUNCTION IS NOT WORKING!
3. A function taking pointer to the structure as an argument: void processPacket(valuesStruct* valuesStructData)

At this moment I noticed strange behavior in the 2nd version of the function. I do nothing with the passed argument - the content of all three functions is **the same.** In 2nd case the function reads wrong values from received XBee packet. In the 1st and 3rd case the function performs correctly.

Code:

**ExampleLib.h**

```
#ifndef ExampleLib_h
#define ExampleLib_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <XBee.h>

#define ADDRESS_BROADCAST 0xffff
#define ADDRESS_PC 0x3333

typedef struct
  {
    int valA;
    int valB;
    int valC;
  } valuesStruct;

class ExampleLib
{
public:
    ExampleLib();
    void setSerial(Stream &serial);
    boolean tryReceivePacket();
    void processPacket();
    // THIS FUNCTION IS NOT WORKING!
    void processPacket(valuesStruct valuesStructData);
    void processPacket(valuesStruct* valuesStructData);
private:
    XBee xbee;
    Rx16Response rx16;
};

#endif
```

**ExampleLib.cpp**

The value read in line `byte* packetData = rx16.getData();` is wrong when we trigger `processPacket(valuesStruct valuesStructData)` function. In other cases the behavior is correct.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <XBee.h>
#include "ExampleLib.h"

ExampleLib::ExampleLib()
{
    xbee = XBee();
    rx16 = Rx16Response();
}

void ExampleLib::setSerial(Stream &serial)
{
    xbee.setSerial(serial);
}

boolean ExampleLib::tryReceivePacket()
{
    xbee.readPacket();

  if (xbee.getResponse().isAvailable()) {
    // got something

    if (xbee.getResponse().getApiId() == RX_16_RESPONSE) {
      // got a rx packet

      xbee.getResponse().getRx16Response(rx16);
      return true;
    } 
    else {
      return false;
    }
  } 
  else if (xbee.getResponse().isError()) {
    //nss.print("Error reading packet.  Error code: ");  
    //nss.println(xbee.getResponse().getErrorCode());
    // or flash error led
    return false;
  } 

  return false;
}
void ExampleLib::processPacket()
{
  byte* packetData = rx16.getData();
  byte dataLength = rx16.getDataLength();
  Serial.print("START L:");
  Serial.println(dataLength);
  for (int i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) { 
    Serial.print(packetData[i]);
    Serial.print(" - "); 
  }
  Serial.println("END");

  //16-bit addressing: Enter address of remote XBee, typically the coordinator
  Tx16Request tx = Tx16Request(ADDRESS_PC, packetData, sizeof(packetData));
  xbee.send(tx);
}

void ExampleLib::processPacket(valuesStruct valuesStructData)
{
  processPacket();
}

void ExampleLib::processPacket(valuesStruct* valuesStructData)
{
  processPacket();
}
```

**Arduino sketch**

```
#include <XBee.h>
#include <ExampleLib.h>

ExampleLib exampleLibObj = ExampleLib();

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  exampleLibObj.setSerial(Serial);
}

void loop()
{

  boolean isPacketReceived = exampleLibObj.tryReceivePacket();

  if (isPacketReceived) {
    // leave only one section, the rest should be commented

    //Section 1: working
    exampleLibObj.processPacket();

    //Section 2: not working
//    valuesStruct test;
//    test.valA = 0;
//    test.valB = 0;
//    test.valC = 0;
//    exampleLibObj.processPacket(test);

    //Section 3: working
//  valuesStruct* test;
//  test->valA = 0;
//  test->valB = 0;
//  test->valC = 0;
//  exampleLibObj.processPacket(test);
  }
}
```

I am really puzzled why in this one case function is performing differently. Looking forward to any suggestions to that issue.

Thanks,
Michal

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't your section 3 that's causing problems?  Because you're declaring a pointer to a structure, but not allocating memory for that structure.

You'd typically write your code like this:

```
valuesStruct test;
test.valA = 0;
test.valB = 0;
test.valC = 0;

//Section 2: not working
exampleLibObj.processPacket(test);

//Section 3: working
exampleLibObj.processPacket(&test);
```

But you also wouldn't typically pass a structure to a function -- you'd pass a pointer to that structure.  There really isn't a need for your second sample.